# Is it better to handle this Query on MySQL side or PHP side?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

### Explanation:

Writing an extension for a closed-source PHP Program,
I need to add some numbers based on these example Queries

```
SELECT sum(value) AS sum1 FROM table WHERE user_id=X AND text='TEXT_HERE_A'
SELECT sum(value) AS sum2 FROM table WHERE user_id=X AND text='TEXT_HERE_B'
```

Add these numbers in PHP and then Update a field in database

```
$update = $sum1 + $sum2 - $php_sum;
UPDATE table SET value=$update WHERE user_id=X
```

### Question:

As you can see I'm searching based on "text" data type in MySql,

Do you think this action is okay? or should I do the following instead:

```
SELECT value,text FROM table WHERE user_id=X
```

and then do the sum and calculations in PHP side through loops (the difference here is I select based on user_id KEY(INT) only, and the sums are calculated are PHP side)

Which one has better performance in large tables?

> Question: Which one is better in this situation? Calculating SUMs in PHP side or MySQL side?

Comment: Can you provide the explain plans for the queries above? The answer will probably come down to benchmarking. Unless these tables are _huge_ it's probably more elegant to just do it in MySQL.

----
explain extended SELECT sum(value) AS sum1 FROM table WHERE user_id=X AND text='TEXT_HERE_A'

Comment: I do not understand your question, but from the looks of your explanation, you do not need php for the arithmetic

Comment: In the second method, I'm SELECTing based on user_id which is KEY (INT) so much faster Select, and then calculating sums in PHP side, in first method I select sums based on searching in TEXT fields

Comment: Why not put it in *one* query ``WHERE `user_id`=X AND (`text`='TEXT_HERE_B' OR `text`='TEXT_HERE_B')``? Even the update could be included - with a subquery or if there has to be updated many rows with the same value, with a SQL variable.

Comment: In general, you should try to do as much as reasonably possible in the database server, and minimize the amount of data that has to be sent from the server to the client. There may be exceptions, but not for simple queries like this.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the _actual_ queries.  I am afraid you have simplified the query to the point where our advice will be incorrect for the _actual_ query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually wrong to return lots of rows and do the filtering and summing in the client -- you generally want to minimize the amount of data transferred between the client and server. So if you can do the filtering with a `WHERE` clause and aggregation with things like `SUM` and `COUNT`, it's usually preferable.

I would try to do the whole thing on the server.

```
UPDATE table AS t1
JOIN (SELECT SUM(value) AS total_value
      FROM table
      WHERE user_id = X AND text in ('TEXT_HERE_A', 'TEXT_HERE_B')) AS t2
SET value = total_value - $php_sum 
WHERE user_id = X
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the values on your PHP-side code, then simply do the entire operation in one query.

Since now you have multiple queries in your example, your code is prone to concurrency anomalies - interleaved execution will leave your final value at the `UPDATE` statement inconsistent.

Since your question also asked about `TEXT` type query, it really depends on what sort of data you are putting into the `TEXT` column. If you can use a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` instead and put an index on that column, the query would be faster. `TEXT` unindexed search would take rather long, and it is expensive to index a `TEXT` column.